# How to Reset Full-Screen Terminal.app Preferences to Factory Defaults

Tags: macos, terminal, preferences, display

On an iMac running Mac OS X version 10.7.5 I have accidentally resized Terminal.app to full-screen (272 x 76) and am unable to resize Terminal.app to a smaller size.  How do I resize Terminal.app to the factory default size or a size where I can use the mouse to resize Terminal.app?

Answer (score 1):

You have (at least) wo possibilities:

1)
You could click on the zoom button to revert the zoom effect (the green circle in the upper left corner in the image below:
[image]

2) You can enter smaller values for the window size under "Preferences":
[image]